# Could not find declaration file for enzyme-adapter-react-16?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, enzyme

I've been using Enzyme to test components in my React application for some time. After updating my packages for the first time in a few weeks I've started getting an error from my tests.

```
 FAIL  src/__tests__/title.test.ts
  ● Testing title component › renders
Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none. [...] 
To find out more about this, see http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/index.html
```

I proceed to install `'enzyme-adapter-react-16'` as described in the link and add the following lines to my test file:

```
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

However, as my application is written in TypeScript, I now run into two new problems.

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

To clarify the images the first error, TS7016, is that there aren't any types for `enzyme-adapter-react-16`, and the second error, TS2339, says that `enzyme` does not have the property `configure`.

I'm relatively new to TypeScript so I need some help. I've tried to install types for `enzyme-adapter-react-16` but those do not appear to exist.

**Should I attempt to add them myself, or is there some way I can avoid this problem all together?**

Also curious what made this error appear. I didn't need an Adapter before, why now?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue for me. I'm using `enzyme-adapter-react-16.2` with `"enzyme": "^3.6.0"`. I do have `@types/enzyme 3.1.13` type declarations file installed though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Should I attempt to add them myself, or is there some way I can avoid this problem all together?

I believe you are correct that there are currently no types for `enzyme-adapter-react-16` - it's pretty new, so it would seem that no one has created any yet.

You can create them yourself, and if you thought they were well defined, you could potentially contribute them to [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) for others to use. To "avoid" the issue, you can get TypeScript to ignore the fact that it has no type information.

To ignore the type errors:

- For the first error, the error message tries to help with the "add a new declaration (.d.ts) file ...". So, you could create a file (I usually put it in a folder called "/types") called something like `enzymeAdapter.d.ts`, and make the contents `declare module 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';` (from the error message).  This basically tells typescript to just treat the imported object as `any` type (ie. no type checking).
- For the second error, you can cast the `enzyme` import to `any`, then call `configure`. For example: `(enzyme as any).configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });`.  If tslint complains about using `any`, you can get it to ignore just that line with a `// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any` comment above.

Full code:

```
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
(enzyme as any).configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

> Also curious what made this error appear. I didn't need an Adapter before, why now?

This is a new design choice from the `enzyme` project for version 3 - you can read details about the major changes from version 2.x [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md). I think the adapter approach is to make handling the different requirements for supporting different versions of react easier and more consistent.

Comment: No problem @langkilde :) For future people, these should only be temporary work-arounds until the typings catch up with the libraries.

Comment: @langkilde FYI: updating to the latest version of `@types/enzyme` (v2.8.9) should now include the `configure` function, so the 2nd error work-around should no longer be required. People move fast!

Comment: do i need to put these adapter configuration line in each test file?

Comment: @th1rdey3 You only need to configure Enzyme once for a test run (for any number of tests). When using `create-react-app` I put it in the [`src/setupTests.js`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#initializing-test-environment) file which runs once before any tests do. Check out the docs for your test runner and it should have a way to do something similar.

Comment: It looks like wonderful open source contributors have now added [types for `enzyme-adapter-react-16`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16)  so neither work around should be needed any more.

Comment: @JonoJob I have sort of related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284074/syntaxerror-use-of-reserved-word-import-running-enzyme-with-karma could you please see if you can help! TIA

Comment: I found the syntax ```import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';``` didnt work, but ```import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';``` did. The first produced an error ```Adapter is not a constructor```. I also had to change ```(enzyme as any).configure({adapter: new Adapter()});``` to ```(enzyme).configure({adapter: new Adapter()});```. Just fyi

Answer (score 17):

It you are using React 16+ and have ejected your app add the following packages:

```
yarn add enzyme react-test-renderer enzyme-adapter-react-16 --dev
```

Then you have to set up Enzyme by creating the file src/setupTests.js. Add this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Finally you have to amend the package.json - add `/src/setupTests.js` to the setupFiles array:

```
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js",
  "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
],
```

[Amend setupFiles array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OQ44.png)

Before:
[Before screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ysQ.png)

After:
[After screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNGvz.png)

I think we can all agree that green is a lovely colour!!

Answer (score 5):

Took me way too long to solve. Hope this helps someone:

Using Create-React-App 2.1.3 with enzyme 3.8.0, enzyme-adapter-react-16: 1.7.1, enzyme-to-json 23.6.0

Solution for me:

src/setupTests.js :

```
import Enzyme, { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16"


configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

then in say component you want to test w/ enzyme & jest:

```
import React from "react";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Component from "./component";

const { shallow } = Enzyme; //whatever you want to use here



test("component exists", () => {
  expect(Component).toBeDefined();
});
```

//this isn't necessary, but just for completeness sake -- no other config is happening:

package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
      }
```

Comment: Why did you import configure 2 times, then overwrite it 2 times?
This is ---> Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
is the same as ---> configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

Answer (score 4):

You should add its type for typescript. You can use this npm package:

```
npm i @types/enzyme-adapter-react-16 --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also noted this issue on windows with a simple typo in my import statement (linting saved me here):

```
import Enzyme from 'Enzyme';
```

rather than

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
```