# SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'import' running enzyme with karma

Tags: reactjs, gruntjs, requirejs, karma-runner, enzyme

Tried unit testing my React application with Enzyme v3, did not work. PFB the details:

modules installed:

```
"enzyme": "^3.1.1",
"enzyme-adapter-react-15.4": "^1.0.5",
```

Created a file **enzyme.config.js**:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15.4';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Included the above file in my karma runner conf:

```
files: [
        // test setup
        ...........
        'test/unit/testutils/enzyme.config.js',
        ..........
]
```

Got following error:

```
14 11 2017 16:21:48.962:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket GWRhv0qSSmqs4UrpAAAC with id 5625410
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'import'
  at test/unit/testutils/enzyme.config.js:1
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if PhantomJs understands `import` - perhaps try using a `require` import instead to see if it makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using babel? You should, one way would be using babel-register before runing the tests, and use the following .babelrc file: (install its dependencies)

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
  ]
}
```

Or install [karma-babel-preprocessor](https://github.com/babel/karma-babel-preprocessor)

karma.conf:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel'],
      'test/**/*.js': ['babel']
    },
    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        presets: ['env'],
        sourceMap: 'inline'
      },
    ...
```